# Switching (su) to a paswordless account

Tags: terminal, su, terminal-emulator, passwd

I've made account A passwordless with `passwd -d A`.  Now, when I log in as user B from a terminal and run `su A` I can switch to user A (and I am not even asked for a password).  If, however, I log as user B into an X window system, open up a terminal emulator and run `su A` I am asked for a password but authentication always fails.  Why the behavior of `su A` is different when run from an emulator and can I achieve the effect in an emmulator as I get when logged in from a terminal window?

**EDIT**

This is what is appended to `/var/log/auth.log` when I `su` in a terminal:

```
su[3751]: Successful su for root by angel
su[3751]: + /dev/tty1 angel:root
su[3751]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by angel(uid=1000)
```

And this is what is appended to `/var/log/auth.log` when I `su` in a terminal emulator:

```
su[3803]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/1 ruser=angel rhost=  user=root
su[3803]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
su[3803]: FAILED su for root by angel
su[3803]: - /dev/pts/1 angel:root
```

Comment: What does `/var/log/auth.log` say about either approach?